# Getting "this" of an ES6 class to call methods and get data members

Tags: javascript, syntax, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I want to call other class methods from inside a class but when some method call a method, I lose access to `this` because now `this` is the calling method and can't other class methods or get data members.

For example:

```
class someclass{

    _this = this;

    foo(){
        this.bar();
    }

    bar(){
        this.baz();  // this is foo not someclass
        _this.baz(); // _this is not defined
    }

    baz(){

    }
}
```

So how can I always have access to the actual class to be able to call its methods and use its data members from its methods?

EDIT: in my actual code, I have another object that calls `foo` with an event, so `this` is that object when entering `foo` and not `someclass`.

Comment: If `this` inside `foo` is wrong, then whatever code is calling `foo` is calling it in a way that discards the correct `this`. How are you calling `foo`? You probably want to use an arrow function _there_.

Comment: There's an event that calls `foo`. @loganfsmyth

Comment: You already have access to the actual class. It's the very meaning of `this`.

Comment: When you pass `foo` to the other function which is going to call it, pass it as `() => obj.foo()`, instead of `obj.foo` as you are most likely doing. It would be highly helpful if you would post that part of your code, since that's almost certainly where the problem lies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Class methods in Javascript are not bound by default. Meaning 
`this` value depends on how they were called, not how they 
were defined.

**To bind (maintain `this`) in ES6:**

```
class SomeClass {
    constructor() {
       // This binding maintains the value of this 
       // inside these methods during future calls. 
       this.foo = this.foo.bind(this)
       this.bar = this.bar.bind(this)
       this.baz = this.baz.bind(this)
    }

    foo() {
        this.bar();
        console.log('from foo')
    }

    bar() {
        this.baz();  // This is foo not SomeClass
        console.log('from bar')
    }

    baz() {

    }
}
```

---

```
// If you are using Babel you can use arrow function/methods 
class SomeClass {

    foo = () => {
      this.bar();
      console.log('from foo')
    }

    bar = () => {
      this.baz();  // This is foo not SomeClass
      console.log('from bar')
    }

    baz() {

    }
}

const s = new SomeClass()
s.foo()
```

**Console output:**

```
"from bar"
"from foo"
```

Comment: Why a regular function doesn't behave the same as an arrow function?

Comment: in javascript class methods are not bound by default

Comment: This is not standard ES6, and the question never mentioned Babel anywhere.

Comment: I use Babel and this works, why it isn't standard ES6? @loganfsmyth

Comment: What do you mean bound by default? @aeid

Comment: In this first example, the `bind` calls are completely unnecessary. The second example won't work at all.

Comment: @torazaburo second example is a feature of react , and yes in this particular context the bindings are unnecessary . I couldn't think of an example where they would lose the this context .

Comment: They lose context in cases like `setTimeout(obj.foo)`, which has been addressed about a thousand times here, and which is almost certainly the OP's underlying problem, although he failed to mention it. Today all you need is `setTimeout(() => obj.foo())`; `bind` is rarely necessary or desirable these days.

Comment: Even if `obj.foo` is declared as an arrow function, will it still lose context? @torazaburo

Comment: If you declare it as an arrow function, it's `this` will be the surrounding context in which you are defining the class, not the class, which is certainly not what you want. This is all covered quite well in dozens if not hundreds of question right here on SO.

Comment: Well I didn't find anything relevant when I searched. Passing `()=>func()` works too though. @torazaburo

Comment: @torazaburo Class fields run with a `this` binding set to the instance. That is currently part of their defined behavior, which is why the arrows work here.

Comment: @kuhaku Babel implements many things. This particular feature is https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/, which is just a proposal for the language, and has not been accepted yet. They are fine to use, but since they are nonstandard there is always the chance that it could change in the future and you'd have to rewrite part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
        class someClass2 {
           bar() {
            console.log('bar from someClass2')
          }
    
        }
    
       class someClass {
          
           constructor() {
             //instantiate an object of someClass2 to access all itsmethod
             this.obj2 = new someClass2()
             
           }
    
           foo () {
            console.log('foo from someClass')
          }
          barFromObj2(){
            return this.obj2.bar()
          }
      }
    
        var obj = new someClass();
    
        obj.foo(); // return foo from someClass
    
        // access the bar method from the someClass2
        obj.barFromObj2(); // return bar from someClass2
```

Comment: But I lose the state of the original object no?

Comment: I have updated my answer to help you understand classes in js.